# Complex Numbers Triangle Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an Argand diagram, $O$ is the origin and the points $P$ and $Q$ represent the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively.

If $\triangle OPQ$ is equilateral, prove that $z_1^2+z_2^2=z_1z_2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433576/if-z-12z-22z-32-z-1z-2z-2z-3z-3z-1-pt-z-1-z-2-z-3-represent-the-ver/3433581#3433581

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$. Given that $z_1,z_2$ forms an equilateral triangle,

$$w=e^{\pm i\frac\pi3}\implies w^3 + 1 = (w^2-w+1)(w+1) = 0\implies w^2-w+1=0$$

i.e. $z_1^2 + z_2^2 = z_1z_2$.

Comment: You've actually proven the converse of the desired result, but you can fix that with an edit.

Comment: @J.G. - Thanking for spotting it. will do

Answer (score 0):

If $\bigtriangleup OPQ$ is equilateral and $P$ is at a point $z_1=re^{i\alpha}$, since $OP=OQ$ and $\measuredangle OPQ=\pm\frac\pi3$, $z_2=re^{i\left(\alpha\pm\frac\pi3\right)}$. Therefore, $$z_1^2+z_2^2=r^2e^{2i\alpha}\left(1+e^{\pm\frac{2i}3}\right)=r^2e^{2i\alpha}\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt3}2\right)=r^2e^{2i\left(\alpha\pm\frac\pi3\right)}=z_1z_2.$$ $\blacksquare$